# Mule Caching Strategy using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, caching, mule

I'm trying to implement cache policy for specific request in mule, use with MongoDB.

***namespace*** - `xmlns:mongo="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo"`

***schemalocation*** - `http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo/current/mule-mongo.xsd`

Try 2 ways:

**1)** I configured the MongoDB connector.

***connector*** - `<mongo:config name="Mongo_DB" doc:name="Mongo DB" database="test" username="test"/>`

***object store for cache*** -

`<ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Mongo_DB_Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy">
        <spring-object-store ref="Mongo_DB" />
    </ee:object-store-caching-strategy>`

But I'm getting the error:

### java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.mule.module.mongo.connectivity.MongoCloudConnectorConnectionManager] to required type [org.mule.api.store.ObjectStore] for property 'store': no matching editors or conversion strategy found.

***2) object store for cache*** - (other way):

like this - [Mule Caching Strategy using Mongo DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138660/mule-caching-strategy-using-mongo-db)

`<ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Mongo_DB_Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy">
        <custom-object-store class="org.mule.module.mongo.MongoObjectStore">
            <spring:property name="database" value="test"/>
            <spring:property name="host" value="localhost"/>
            <spring:property name="port" value="27017"/>
            <spring:property name="username" value="test"/>
        </custom-object-store>
    </ee:object-store-caching-strategy>`

But I'm getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

This config worked for me and used Spring to instantiate the OS.

```
<spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="mongoObjectStore" class="org.mule.module.mongo.MongoObjectStore" 
            init-method="initialize" scope="singleton">
            <spring:property name="host" value="localhost"/>
            <spring:property name="port" value="27017"/>
            <spring:property name="database" value="test"/>
            <spring:property name="username" value=""/>
            <spring:property name="password" value=""/>
            <spring:property name="writeConcern" value="DATABASE_DEFAULT"/>
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>

    <ee:object-store-caching-strategy
        name="mongoCachingStrategy">
        <spring-object-store ref="mongoObjectStore" />
    </ee:object-store-caching-strategy>
```

Comment: It's working!!, I understand you used  it  for cache, where did  you configure TTL for example?

Comment: Do you know something?

Comment: That's a separate question. i see you've opened a new thread. if you're happy with this one you can accept the answer.

Comment: I am getting this error:`Unable to find type 'org.mule.module.mongo.MongoObjectStore' on build path of project 'test'`, how to solve?

Comment: Have you added the Mule Mongo Module as a dependency?